# Correct Regex to remove spaces after or before a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using the regex string below to look for words that in this case are only immediately followed by one space. What am i missing here? This removes any and all spaces, however i need some left. Im only trying to remove words that are immediately followed by a space, how would i do this. An example would be the input being. (One Two Three) The first replace should remove " Three" and the second replace should remove "One " leaving only Two. If i only wanted Three left i would only use the second line of code. My main issue is getting the correct regex pattern here.

```
preg_replace('/\s[A-z]/', '', $data);
preg_replace('/[A-z]\s/', '', $data);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for clearing up the A-z mistake, i assumed A-z would be the entire range, i see now that A-Z is capital and a-z is lowercase, or case insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is that in your example, "Two" also has a space in front of it. Therefore, the first replace will remove both " Two" and " Three" (once you've changed the `[A-z]` to `[A-Za-z]+`, that is).

I think you want something like this:

```
/\s[a-z]+(?!\s)/i
/(?<!\s)[a-z]+\s/i
```

Note the addition of the `+` quantifier. Without that, the `[a-z]` will only match one character, so your "One Two Three" example will probably result in "On w hree".

Also, `[A-z]` technically results in undefined behavior (and may throw an exception) since capital A to lowercase z isn't a valid range. You want either `[A-Za-z]` or a case-insensitive match using `[a-z]`, as I've done above.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Now that im able to run the code im seeing it maybe un doable as like everyone is saying either replace takes away the middle word. So i could strip leading spaces as (One Two Three) to (One) or following spaces as (One Two Three) to (Three) is there no workaround to leave the word in the middle somehow? This is the best way ive thought of, but it obviously doesnt work for the word in the middle... any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan - The code above should leave the "Two" alone because of the negative lookarounds. You could also use something like `/^[a-z]+\s|\s[a-z]+$/i`, that should do it only for the first and last word in the string.

Comment: The updated code above didnt seem to work in my case, none the less the code you quoted in your comment works perfect. Thanks once again! :)

Answer (score 2):

`[A-z]` matches only one letter - and it it incorrect too because you should declare `[a-zA-Z]` to match all letters upper- and lowercase.

Try with:

```
/\s[a-zA-Z]+/
```

and

```
/[a-zA-Z]+\s/
```

After that, your code should looks like:

```
preg_replace('/\s[a-zA-Z]+/', '', $data);
preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]+\s/', '', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add + to get one or more characters between A and z.

```
preg_replace('/[A-Za-z]+\s/', '', $data);
preg_replace('/\s[A-Za-z]+/', '', $data);
```

Comment: Invalid regular expression: `[A-z]` is not allowed.